# How to use MakeGenericMethod with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to invoke a generic method using a type argument that is parsed at runtime from a string (user input). Here is my test code:

```
        MethodInfo method = typeof(GameManager).GetMethod(nameof(GameManager.SetPreference));
        MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(PlayerData.Preferences), typeof(bool) });
        genericMethod.Invoke(new GameManager(), new object[] { PlayerData.Preferences.WaitMode, true });
```

This fails with "ArgumentException: Incorrect length".

Here is the function I'm calling:

```
public void SetPreference<T>(PlayerData.Preferences preference, T value)
    {
        try
        {
            PlayerData.SetAttr(preference.ToString(), value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError(e);
            return;
        }

        OnPreferenceChanged.Raise(preference);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `MakeGenericMethod` only wants the generic parameter type(s) to be replaced by a concrete type. In your case `typeof(bool)`.
`method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(bool) });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MakeGenericMethod`'s parameters are for the **type-parameters** of the target generic method *not the method parameters*, in your case the `SetPreference` method only has 1 type-parameter: `T`, not 2.

For `SetPreference<Boolean>` pass only `new Type[] { typeof(Boolean) }` - so don't pass `typeof(PlayerData.Preferences)` to `MakeGenericMethod`.

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(GameManager).GetMethod(nameof(GameManager.SetPreference));
MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(bool) });
genericMethod.Invoke(new GameManager(), new object[] { PlayerData.Preferences.WaitMode, true });
```